# if index of div is equal to index of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to get index of elements on page:

```
$('#wrapper section').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-index', $(this).index());
});
```

and then i create div `svs-control` with `data-index` of my sections:

```
$('#wrapper section').each(function(){
   var me = this;
      $('#re_order').append('<div class="svs-control" data-index="'+$(me).index()+'"></div>');
});
```

and now i want to remove each `section` by cicking each `svs-control`, how to compare the index of `section` and `svs-control`,and if they match - delete section?

Comment: you can use the attribute equals selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you're accessing each `section` by index assigning that value to a data attribute is redundant, so your first `each()` loop can be removed. You can use a delegated event handler on the `.svs-control` elements (because they are dynamically appended to the DOM), and lookup the `section` by index using `eq()`:

```
$('#re_order').on('click', '.svs-control', function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    $('#wrapper section').eq(index).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data-index attribute of clicked element to build attribute equals selector and target the section element:

```
$('.svs-control').click(function(){
   $('section[data-index="'+$(this).attr('data-index')+'"]').remove();
});
```